# How Compare two sheet in open office and mark different value with color

Tags: openoffice-calc

In first sheet original data and in second modify data so i want to compare both sheet data and mark with color if sheet1 and sheet2 data not match.

I have two different sheet with data as per below.

Sheet1:

```
--------A-----B-----C
1-------T10---T10---T40
2-------T34---T65---T20
```

Sheet2:

```
--------A-----B-----C
1-------Z10---T10---T40
2-------T34---T65---T20
```

ABC is represent the columns.
1-2 is represent row.

I can write the conditional format on single cell to check if Sheet1.A1 <> Sheet2.A1 and change the background colour.

conditional formatting : "Cell Value is"  "equal to" $Sheet1.A$1      Cell Style "BACK_COLOR_RED".

But the problem is that how can i apply this same conditional format on sheet all cell to compare both sheet as manually write the same formula
on one by one cell is not feasible.

Comment: There's a "Compare Documents" feature available in the `Edit` menu - did you try if it fits your needs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the answer, I hope below answer will also help to other people to run time compare two sheet.

**Step 1:**

[image]

**Step 2:**

[image]

**Step 3:**

[image]

**output**

[image]